# Change renderer class inside custom pagination in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using custom renderer class by default in settings.py. For api I check query parameter "page", if it exist then I paginate result else return normal response using default renderer class from settings.py. But I have problem, I want to use only JSONResponse renderer for pagination

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'app.core.renderers.CustomJSONRenderer',
        "rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer",
        "rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer",
    ),
}
```

renderers.py

```
class CustomJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):
    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        status_code = renderer_context['response'].status_code
        response = {
            "success": True,
            "message": None,
            "data": data,
        }

        return super(CustomJSONRenderer, self).render(response, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

views.py

```
class User_View(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = User_Serializer

    pagination_class = CustomPagination
    ### If page param exist then use pagination class else not use
```

pagination.py

```
class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size_query_param = 'size'
    page_size = int(settings.PAGE_SIZE)

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'success': True,
            'total': self.page.paginator.count,
            'page_size': self.get_page_size(self.request),
            'current_page': self.page.number,
            'last_page': self.page.paginator.num_pages,
            'data': data,
        })
```

wrong response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": null,
    "data": {
        "success": true,
        "total": 6,
        "page_size": 15,
        "current_page": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "admin",
                "permissions": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Correct response (expected):

```
{
        "success": true,
        "total": 6,
        "page_size": 15,
        "current_page": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "admin",
                "permissions": []
            }
        ]
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve problem with updating CustomJSONRenderer class

```
class CustomJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):
    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        status_code = renderer_context['response'].status_code
        request = renderer_context.pop('request')
        page = request.query_params.get('page', None)

        # Check page query params
        if page is not None:
            response = data
        else:
            response = {
                'success': True,
                'message': None,
                'data': data,
            }

        return super(CustomJSONRenderer, self).render(response, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```